# Handling workload of raised events in background threads in C# 4 and controlling the number of threads

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, event-handling, backgroundworker, task-parallel-library

I have a C# 4 application that is subscribing for an event which I expect to be raised a very large number of times in quick succession. Each time it is raised a bit of work is required to be done that I don't really want to block the event thread with.

It feels like I should pass off this "chunk" of work to a background thread / task and allow the event thread to continue, however I also need to make sure that too many threads aren't created as, as I say, I expect this event to be raised a lot of times quickly.

Is there a recognized pattern or recommended approach for passing off event handler workload to background threads but limiting the amount of threads created?

It feels like there should be some way of using the Task Parallel Library for this, but can't find anything that does exactly what I need at the moment.

Let me know if anyone needs any more information, as I appreciate I've been quite general with what I've said.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the “bit of work” that you want to perform each time the event is raised is small and mostly CPU-bound, then just start a `Task` each time. The `ThreadPool` will determine the optimal number of threads to use, which will most likely be close to the number of CPU cores you have. You don't have to worry about limiting the degree of parallelism in this case.

If the work for each raise can take a long time or if it's mostly IO-bound, then you should manually limit the degree of parallelism. One way to do that would be to have a small number of threads that block if there's no work, and otherwise process the events from a queue. You could achieve this by using `BlockingCollection`.

Possibly the best option, if you can use .Net 4.5, is to use `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow with `MaximumDegreeOfParallelism` set. With it, you won't waste any threads when there is no work and you can set the maximum number of threads to be used (or not).

Comment: Yeah the work is mostly IO-bound, it relies on a call to a remote web service and waiting for the response. Unfortunately I don't have access to .NET 4.5, but ActionBlock does sound like what i'm after!

Answer (score 1):

Don't create any threads during the app run.  Create, (or depool), tasks when the event fires and submit/queue them to the threadpool.

If you don't actaully create any threads, (except at startup for the ones serving the thread pool), you cannot create too many threads!

You can create too many tasks, but there are other mechansims to limit this, (I usually create a fixed number of tasks at startup as well, but many more than the number of threads, and pool them in a BlockingCollection, popping/loading/submitting/puishingBack during the run, so providing data/task flow-control).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it is better to use the task API as opposed to creating my own threads but I was really looking for an example of how to control/limit the creation of/assignment to tasks as the events are fired and a reasonable approach for deciding this limit.

Comment: How big, (space-wise), are your tasks?  If they contain 10MB of network data buffer, you could not create so many:).  I often just pick a number with a wet finger, 256, say:)  It's farily easy to make an object pool depth configurable and/or changeable during run-time, for optimization - if the requested pool depth is less than the actual pool depth, create more tasks in a loop.   If the requested pool depth is less than the actual pool depth, stop repooling returned tasks until requested=actual, so that the surplus tasks get GC'd.

Comment: How exactly are you pooling `Task`s? I don't think it's possible, because once a `Task` completes, you can't restart it.

Comment: Once a thread terminates, you cannot restart it.  A task object is just an object - you can do what you want with it - null its last ref to ensure it gets GC'd or push it back onto a BlockingCollection for re-use.

Comment: Yes, but it is an object with specific semantics. And that semantics says that once you set its result, you can't “unset” it. Because of that, reusing `Task` the way you describe is impossible. (You could push a new `Task` to the collection, but that wouldn't be pooling and would be useless.)

Comment: That's like saying you can ignore the fact that `int` can only store integers and advising to store strings in it. `Task` is what it is, you can't change how it behaves. You can't not use its semantics.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBlock and the rest of the TPL Dataflow is also available for .NET 4 in the form of a CTP - for main scenarios it is solid (I'm using the CTP in a large project without any problems - of course your mileage may differ)

The dataflow blocks will even allow you to create a pipeline if you have other work that needs to be done after calling your remote web-service (eg: collation of results, updating logs)